# Single update last row entry for a set of IDs - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I want to execute an update for a set of Ids in a history table using `IN(1,2,3)`. There is, of course, more than one entry for the same id in the table. For each id, the update should only be performed in the last history entry.

Is there a way to perform this with a single update?

```
UPDATE table SET fk_something = 123 WHERE id_something IN (1,2,3) AND ...?
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know what is the last entry?  Do you have a date field or some other indicator for last?

Comment: Yes. I have an updated_at datetime field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a column to determine what the last date is, then you can use an `UPDATE` with a subquery similar to this:

```
update yourtable t1
inner join
(
  select max(updated_at) MaxDate, id_something
  from yourtable 
  group by id_something
) t2
  on t1.id_something = t2.id_something
  and t1.updated_at = t2.MaxDate
set t1.fk_something = 123
where t1.id_something IN (1,2,3)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b56b3/1).

This uses a subquery to get the `max(updated_at)` value for each `id_something`.  These rows are then joined to your table to make sure that you update the latest row.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
 UPDATE yourtable 
 SET fk_something = 123 
 WHERE id_something=1
 ORDER BY datecreated DESC
 LIMIT 0,1
 ;
 UPDATE yourtable 
 SET fk_something = 123 
 WHERE id_something=2
 ORDER BY datecreated DESC
 LIMIT 0,1
 ;
 ...
```

Just wrap it up in a procedure to simplify. (note you'll need to use prepare/execute if you're passing a CSV list as an argument)